# SQL Server Native Connection not actually connecting as expected

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I'm working in an environment where I have to connect to an app server using a CyberArk account and once logged in, I can access the Pentaho Data Integrator tool.

From within this tool, I created a connection to the database server using SQL Server Native. When I test the connection, it connects successfully. A simple SQL Script step query "Select x from table y" provides accurate results. When I create a SQL Script step and test the user account, "select suser_name()" it returns the account used to login to the Pentaho server via CyberArk, not the configured account used in the connection object. Because of this, I can't execute stored procedures created specifically for the account used in the connection object.
Is there a configuration for Pentaho that I'm missing?

Comment: Forgot to mention... Sql Server 2016, Pentaho Spoon v6

Comment: Are you tried to give the username owner privilege on db?

Comment: Yes, I have tried giving the user DBO privs and that works for testing purposes however, it violates security because it's a shared account.
The account configured in the connection object is a service account that already has DBO privileges.